# How to specify location permission reason in expo-location react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

Apple rejected my app because I didn't specify the reason why I'm requesting user location permission.
I'm using Expo (react-native managed workflow). Is there a way I can specify my reason in the permission request.